# Executar um JavaScript no Webbrowser com Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Criei um robô em Delphi para abrir um site e incluir os dados automaticamente.

Estou com problema para chamar uma rotina JavaScript que tem neste site, conforme abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function prepararInclusaoItem(id) {
    myForm = document.getElementById('faturaForm');
    myForm.action='faturamentoPrepararInclusaoItem.do';
    myForm.id.value = id;
}
function excluirItem(codigo) {
    if(confirm('Deseja realmente excluir este Item de Pagamento?')) {
        navegarPara('ExcluirItem', codigo);
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

E para acessar o registro tem a rotina que chama o script :

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: Cara, eu não sei se você consegue disparar esses métodos em Javascript. Mas pelo que me parece, são 2 objetos que vão incluir e excluir alguma coisa. Sendo assim ,você poderia disparar pelo Delphi, a ação desse determinado objeto (supondo que seja um botão)

Answer (score -1):

Existe Esta Forma: `WebBrowser1.EvaluateJavaScript('NomeDaFunction');`

Answer (score -1):

Usei o comando:

```
WebBrowser1.EvaluateJavaScript(vvScript);
```

Funcionou!